# What is the good way to remember the signs of the rotational matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, intuition, rotations, mnemonic

Recall rotational matrix in (x,y) is given by:

$R =  \begin{bmatrix}  \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$

For the life of me I cannot remember if the top right **sin** entry has a negative or positive sign, and I have known this matrix since 5 years ago (obviously I am a failure!!).

Sure one could always derive from first principle via:

[image]

But if someone just went up to you and asked you to write down the matrix, what is a good way in the least time write down the matrix and verify that it is correct (with the correct signs)?

Comment: Apply on the standard basis vectors.

Comment: Maybe you can check with $R_{\pi /2}$ maps $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$,or something similar, just like what @Raskolnikov says.

Comment: View the matrix as a collection of column vectors, the $k^{th}$ column is where the $k^{th}$ standard basis should go. For example, when one apply a counterclockwise rotation of small angle $\theta$ to the unit vector $\hat{x}$, it will pick up a little bit in the +ve $y$-direction. So the sign in front of the $\sin\theta$ in lower left corner of the rotation matrix is +ve.

Comment: Check the determinant to make sure it's 1 ... $\cos^{2}+\sin^{2}=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\theta=\pi/2$, and write down one of the options. It is fairly easy to check in this case whether you got a clockwise or anti-clockwise rotation.

Answer (score 8):

Use complex numbers.

To rotate $x + iy$ through an angle $\theta$, multiply by
$e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$

$(x + iy)(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) =
(x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta) + i(x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta)$

which corresponds to

\begin{pmatrix}
   \cos \theta & -\sin \theta\\
   \sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}

Practically, all you really need to figure out is that the real part is
$x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta$, or that the imaginary part is
$x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta$.

I just remember that the signs in the top row are $1^2$ and $i^2$.

Answer (score 2):

My idea is similar to Steven's.

Write complex numbers in vector forms on the complex plane.
Rotating $\begin{pmatrix} \cos{\gamma}\\\sin{\gamma}\end{pmatrix}$ through angle $\theta$ counterclockwise, 
it is located at $\begin{pmatrix} \cos{(\gamma+\theta)}\\\sin{(\gamma+\theta)}\end{pmatrix}$.
By the Trigonometric Addition Formulas, 
$$\cos{(\gamma+\theta)}=\cos{\gamma}\cos{\theta}-\sin{\gamma}\sin{\theta},$$
$$\sin{(\gamma+\theta)}=\sin{\theta}\cos{\gamma}+\sin{\gamma}\cos{\theta},$$
you can know the matrix $A$ which satisfies 
$$A
\begin{pmatrix} \cos{\gamma}\\\sin{\gamma}\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} \cos{(\gamma+\theta)}\\\sin{(\gamma+\theta)}\end{pmatrix}$$
is 
$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos{\theta}& -\sin{\theta} \\ \sin{\theta}& \cos{\theta} \end{pmatrix}.$$